# An entangled system vs. a classical statistical mixture; is there any measurable difference between them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

We know that systems A and B, if given any coupling will in general entangle. If we just focus ourselves to measurement outcomes on A, the density matrix $\rho_A$ formed from a partial trace describes all measurement outcomes and in particular can always be restated as

$\rho_A = \sum_i p_i \left|\psi_i\right>\left<\psi_i\right|$

where $p_i$ are probabilities.

Is there any measurable difference between particle in a state $\rho_A$ constructed from entanglement and a particle in a state determined by a machine which classically (via computer) randomly chooses a state $\left|\psi_i\right>$ with probability $p_i$. In one measurement? In infinitely many measurements?

Comment: @JohnForkosh I am not asking if a mixed state is the same as  a pure state. Im asking if there are two ways to construct a mixed state via entanglement vs sampling from an ensemble of pure states of $|\psi>$ with probabilities of$p_i$